# Show if a family of maps if bounded pointwise, then it is bounded uniformly on a dense subset of an open ball

Tags: banach-spaces, baire-category

> Let $M',M$ be metric spaces with $M$ a Baire space. If any family $(f_i)_i$ of maps $M\to M'$ is bounded pointwise on $M$, then it is also bounded uniformly on a dense subset of an open ball in $M$.

My attempt:

Suppose that $(f_i)_i$ is bounded pointwise on $M$. Let $a_0\in M$, then $$ (\forall x\in M)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall i\in I)(d(f_i(x),a_0)\le N).$$ Let $V_N :=\overline{\{x\in M\mid \forall i\in I: d(f_i(x),a_0)\le N\}}$. These sets are closed in $M$, and moreover, $M=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}V_N$. Baire implies that $\exists N: V_N^°\ne \emptyset$, or, there is an non-empty open ball $B$ such that $B\subseteq V_N$. So, let $x\in B$, then $\exists x_n\in V_N: x_n\to x$. By definition $d(f_i(x_n),a_0)\le N, \forall i,n$.

I think our main goal is to find open and dense subsets $U_n$ in $M$, which would imply $\bigcap_n U_n$ is dense in $M$ + show that this intersection is contained in some open ball so that $(f_i)_i$ is bounded uniformly on this set... The maps $f_i$ are not necessarily continuous, so it gets harder to construct a ball on which these maps are bounded uniformly.

Any tips?